# NoReverseMatch Error Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-urls

Quiero intentar pasar el id del post como argumento utilizando {% url %} templates, pero me sale el siguiente error. Alguien me podría decir que pasa o que tengo mal?

```
NoReverseMatch at /blog/post/1/
Reverse for 'post' with keyword arguments '{'article_id': 1}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog/post/<int:article_id>/']
```

Os dejo el link del repo por si quereis mirarlo mejor: [github](https://github.com/Crzek/NewsPost)
Para conseguir la APIKEY: [NewsAPIFree](https://newsapi.org/).

utilizo python 3.11 y Django 4.2

Mis Archivos:
blog/views.py

```
def post(request, article_id):
    if POST:
        article = POST[article_id]

    else:
        article = Post.objects.get(id=article_id)

    return render(
        request,
        "post.html",
        context={
            "article": article,
            "date": datetime.date.today()
        })
```

blog/urls.py

```
from django.urls import re_path
from .views import index, add_post, post

app_name = "blog"

urlpatterns = [
    # Your code here
    re_path("", index, name="index"),
    re_path("add_post/", add_post, name="addpost"),
    re_path("post/<int:article_id>/", post, name="post"),

]
```

Se suponen que ele error esta en el tag `<a>` en blog.html

```
        {% for art in articles %} 
            <a href="{% url 'blog:post' article_id=art.id  %}" class="box">
                <div >
                    <h2>{{art.id}}</h2>
                    <h3>{{art.title}}</h3>
                    <h5>Date (DD-MM-YYYY):{{date.day}}-{{date.month}}-{{date.year}}</h5>
                    <p>{{art.description}}</p>
                </div>
            </a>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

lo he soluciodado.

En mi caso es que estoy utilizando `re_path` que se usan con expresiones regulares, esto hacía que no encuentre la url correcta, porque pruebe de llamar la view post. y vi que me estaba llamando siempre la función index (eso no es normal), tiene que llamar la función de la view, asi que probé en, usar `path` me a ha funciona todo bien, ha pasado los parámetros y todo.

Solucion:

```
app_name = "blog"

urlpatterns = [
    # Your code here
    path("", index, name="index"),
    path("add_post/", add_post, name="addpost"),
    path("post/<int:article_id>/", post, name="post"),

]
```